# Reading last few rows using read_csv in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a file which is continuously growing like this:

```
https|webmail.mahindracomviva.com|application/vnd.ms-sync.wbxml|158|POST|203.101.110.171
https|webmail.mahindracomviva.com||0|POST|203.101.110.171
https|webmail.mahindracomviva.com||0|POST|203.101.110.171
https|www.googleapis.com|application/x-protobuf|246|POST|74.125.200.95
https|webmail.mahindracomviva.com|application/vnd.ms-sync.wbxml|140|POST|203.101.110.171
https|webmail.mahindracomviva.com|application/x-protobuf|52|POST|203.101.110.171
https|www.googleapis.com|application/x-protobuf|502|POST|74.125.200.95
https|www.googleapis.com|application/x-protobuf|40|POST|74.125.200.95
```

But I would like to read only the last 50 lines using Pandas.

Comment: Does anything in [this other question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108250/efficiently-read-last-n-rows-of-csv-into-dataframe) help?

Comment: What OS are you using. In *nix you can first create a file with `tail -n 50 long_file.csv > short_file.csv`, and use it

Comment: Please improve the question. How does one read the "last 50 lines" of a file that's continuously growing? The last line has not arrived yet.

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow this steps:

1. First find the length of CSV file without loading the whole CSV files into the ram.
   You have to use chunksize in read_csv().

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   count = 0
   for data in pd.read_csv('YourFile.csv',encoding = 'ISO-8859-1',chunksize  = 1000):
       count += 1                          # counting the number of chunks
       lastlen = len(data)                 # finding the length of last chunk
   datalength = (count*1000 + lastlen - 1000) # length of total file
   ```
2. Second minus the no of rows which you want to read.

   ```
   rowsdiff = datalen - 300
   df = pd.read_csv('YourFile.csv',encoding = 'ISO-8859-1',skiprows = range(1,difrows), nrows = 299)
   ```

By this method you have to read only last few lines without laoding the whole CSV file into the ram

Answer (score -1):

Try using the pandas tail(), line so:

```
filename = "your_file"
last_rows = 3
data = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, sep = "|")
print(data.tail(last_rows))
```