# Read the last N lines of a CSV file in Python with numpy / pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy

Is there a quick way to read the last N lines of a CSV file in Python, using `numpy` or `pandas`?

1. I cannot do `skip_header` in `numpy` or `skiprow` in `pandas` because the length of the file varies, and I would always need the last N rows.
2. I know I can use pure Python to read line by line from the last row of the file, but that would be very slow. I can do that if I have to, but a more efficient way with `numpy` or `pandas` (which is essentially using C) would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With a small 10 line test file I tried 2 approaches - parse the whole thing and select the last N lines, versus load all lines, but only parse the last N:

```
In [1025]: timeit np.genfromtxt('stack38704949.txt',delimiter=',')[-5:]
1000 loops, best of 3: 741 µs per loop

In [1026]: %%timeit 
      ...: with open('stack38704949.txt','rb') as f:
      ...:      lines = f.readlines()
      ...: np.genfromtxt(lines[-5:],delimiter=',')

1000 loops, best of 3: 378 µs per loop
```

This was tagged as a duplicate of [Efficiently Read last 'n' rows of CSV into DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108250/efficiently-read-last-n-rows-of-csv-into-dataframe).  The accepted answer there used

```
from collections import deque
```

and collected the last N lines in that structure.  It also used `StringIO` to feed the lines to the parser, which is an unnecessary complication.  `genfromtxt` takes input from anything that gives it lines, so a list of lines is just fine.

```
In [1031]: %%timeit 
      ...: with open('stack38704949.txt','rb') as f:
      ...:      lines = deque(f,5)
      ...: np.genfromtxt(lines,delimiter=',') 

1000 loops, best of 3: 382 µs per loop
```

Basically the same time as `readlines` and slice.

`deque` may have an advantage when the file is very large, and it gets costly to hang onto all the lines.  I don't think it saves any file reading time.  Lines still have to be read one by one.

timings for the `row_count` followed by `skip_header` approach are slower; it requires reading the file twice.  `skip_header` still has to read lines.

```
In [1046]: %%timeit 
      ...: with open('stack38704949.txt',"r") as f:
      ...:       ...:     reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter = ",")
      ...:       ...:     data = list(reader)
      ...:       ...:     row_count = len(data)
      ...: np.genfromtxt('stack38704949.txt',skip_header=row_count-5,delimiter=',')

The slowest run took 5.96 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 760 µs per loop
```

For purposes of counting lines we don't need to use `csv.reader`, though it doesn't appear to cost much extra time.

```
In [1048]: %%timeit 
      ...: with open('stack38704949.txt',"r") as f:
      ...:    lines=f.readlines()
      ...:    row_count = len(data)
      ...: np.genfromtxt('stack38704949.txt',skip_header=row_count-5,delimiter=',')

1000 loops, best of 3: 736 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**

You can read the entire file with `numpy.genfromtxt`, get it as a numpy array, and take the last N rows:

```
a = np.genfromtxt('filename', delimiter=',')
lastN = a[-N:]
```

**Option 2**

You can do a similar thing with the usual file reading:

```
with open('filename') as f:
    lastN = list(f)[-N:]
```

but this time you will get the list of last N lines, as strings.

**Option 3 - without reading the entire file to memory**

We use a list of at most N items to hold each iteration the last N lines:

```
lines = []
N = 10
with open('csv01.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        lines.append(line)
        if len(lines) > 10:
            lines.pop(0)
```

A real csv requires a minor change:

```
import csv
...
with ...
    for line in csv.reader(f):
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `skiprows` parameter of `pandas` `read_csv()`, the tougher part is finding the number of lines in the csv. here's a possible solution:

```
with open('filename',"r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter = ",")
    data = list(reader)
    row_count = len(data)

df = pd.read_csv('filename', skiprows = row_count - N)
```